# Open NavigationController on tap of button in MKAnnotationView

Tags: ios, swift, mkannotationview

I have `MKAnnotationView` where I am showing title,subtitle and info button, on tap of location pin.

I have added the following code

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

        if annotation is MKUserLocation {
            //return nil so map view draws "blue dot" for standard user location
            return nil
        }


        let reuseId = "pin"
        let  pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        pinView.canShowCallout = true
        pinView.animatesDrop = true
        pinView.pinTintColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
        pinView.draggable = true
        let btn = UIButton(type: .DetailDisclosure)
        pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = btn

        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self,action: #selector(MapView.calloutTapped(_:)))
        pinView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

        return pinView
    }

    func calloutTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        //   if sender.state != UIGestureRecognizerState.Began { return }
        let annView: MKAnnotationView! = sender.view as? MKAnnotationView
        let ann:MKAnnotation! = annView!.annotation
        print("handlePinButtonTap: ann.title \(ann!.title!!) and \(ann!.subtitle!!)")
        let touchLocation = sender.locationInView(mapView)
        let locationCoordinate = mapView.convertPoint(touchLocation, toCoordinateFromView: mapView)
        print("Tapped at lat: \(locationCoordinate.latitude) long: \(locationCoordinate.longitude)  " )

        let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "ShoppingCart", bundle: nil)
        let vc : ShoppingCartController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ShoppingCart") as! ShoppingCartController


        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)

        self.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)



    }
```

However upon using this code,on tap of the pin on the map, user is navigated to the `ShoppingCart` storyboard. I want to present that ViewController on the tap of info button along with the title,subtitle, latitude and longitude of the event that has been tapped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working solution

```
    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {

        if annotation is MKUserLocation {
            //return nil so map view draws "blue dot" for standard user location
            return nil
        }


        let reuseId = "pin"
        let  pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        pinView.canShowCallout = true
        pinView.animatesDrop = true
        pinView.pinTintColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
        pinView.draggable = true
        let btn = UIButton(type: .DetailDisclosure)
        pinView.rightCalloutAccessoryView = btn

        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self,action: #selector(MapView.calloutTapped(_:)))
        pinView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

        return pinView
    }

    func calloutTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {


        //   if sender.state != UIGestureRecognizerState.Began { return }
        let annView: MKAnnotationView! = sender.view as? MKAnnotationView
        let ann:MKAnnotation! = annView!.annotation
        print("handlePinButtonTap: ann.title \(ann!.title!!) and \(ann!.subtitle!!)")
        let touchLocation = sender.locationInView(mapView)
        let locationCoordinate = mapView.convertPoint(touchLocation, toCoordinateFromView: mapView)
        print("Tapped at lat: \(locationCoordinate.latitude) long: \(locationCoordinate.longitude)  " )
}
```